# Is there geometry_msgs/Twist for rosserial

Tags: arduino, rosserial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,
I am trying to make a driver for my custom Arduino robot and I would like to have the Arduino parse the twist messages itself and publish /odom messages itself. Is this feasible? I looked through the rosserial packages and I couldn't find any of the geometry messages, so any ideas?
Thanks,
luketheduke

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/205802/is-there-geometry_msgs/twist-for-rosserial/) by [luketheduke](https://answers.ros.org/users/20641/luketheduke/) on ROS Answers with karma: 285 on 2015-03-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes. You can `#include <geometry_msgs/Twist.h>` directly into the Arduino code. Just be sure to put `#include <ros.h>` first, before any other `#include` statements.

---

Originally posted by [aak2166](https://answers.ros.org/users/21299/aak2166/) with karma: 593 on 2015-03-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [luketheduke](https://answers.ros.org/users/20641/luketheduke/) on 2015-03-24**:
Thanks that helped!